# Division algorithm in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification

Given the Gaussian integers $\alpha=5+3i,\beta=30+6i$ I want to find Gaussian integers $\gamma,\rho$ such that $\beta=\gamma\alpha+\rho$.

Doing the division immediately we see that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=\frac{30+6i}{5+3i}=\frac{168-60i}{34}$. So the 'nearest' Gaussian integer to $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ is $4-i$. As such we can write $30+6i=(4-i)(5+3i)+\rho$, giving $30+6i=23+2i+\rho$.

Hence $\rho=7+4i$. I want the norm of $\rho$ to be less than the norm of $\alpha$ ; $N(\alpha)<N(\rho)$ here though... How do I solve this?

Comment: If the norm is not in the bounds as you think it should be, then you most likely didn't find the nearest Gaussian integer. Why do you think $4-i$ is the nearest? $\frac{168}{34}$ is almost $5$ and $-\frac{60}{34}i$ is almost $-2i$.

Comment: I took the integer part of $\frac{168-60i}{34}$ - I wonder if I instead should've chosen $5-2i$. In any case I think the correct approach is the division algorithm in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and I'm sadly not quite sure how to do this

Comment: No. Don't take integer part, *round* it. Yes, try with $5-2i$ and let us know how it went.

Comment: @StinkingBishop using $5-2i$ instead we obtain $30+6i=(5-2i)(5+3i)+(-1+i)$ and the conditions are satisfied - thanks!

Comment: You said "Given the Gaussian integers $\alpha=5+3i$, $\beta=30+6i$. I want to find Gaussian integers $\gamma$, $\rho$ such that $\beta = \gamma \alpha + \rho$". But that's not what you really want, because you could take simply $\gamma = 0$ and $\rho = \beta$. In the division algorithm it's **very important** the extra condition on the size of $\rho$.